# Limit with mixed algebraic and trigonometric terms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

I am trying to solve a problem of the indeterminate form 0/0. I'm unable to make much progress using regular limit identities. Is there an approach I am missing? I don't think the solution requires L'hospital rule. I can even make do with hints. A discussion on general approach will suffice.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to a} \left[\dfrac{1}{(x^2 - a^2) ^2}\right]\left[\dfrac{a^2+x^2}{ax}-2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\right]
\end{equation}
Where $a$ is an odd integer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I'll keep it in mind henceforth.

Comment: Please delete the linked image from your posting and edit your posting, using MathJax to display all of the Math.

Comment: @user2661923 done

Comment: Thanks P3p3o for the beautiful edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute x = a + h, and change the limit to a --> 0. This will simplify the entire problem. In the second bracket, the polynomial will become a function of a and h, separate the two. Also, use the identity 2 sin A sin B = Cos (A - B) - Cos (A + B). This was also touched upon in the above post.

Once these two substitutions are made, one only need to use simple algebra.

The answer is $ \frac {\pi ^ 2a^2 + 4} {16 a ^4} $

Answer (score 0):

Long-winded comment.
**Not an answer**.

This is an ugly problem with virtually no educational value that succumbs to an offbeat trick.  L'Hopital's Rule not required.  Numerator cancels out.

---

$\cos(r+s) = \cos(r)\cos(s) - \sin(r)\sin(s).$ 
$\cos(r-s) = \cos(r)\cos(s) + \sin(r)\sin(s).$

Subtracting the 2nd line above from the first line yields

$\cos(r+s) - \cos(r-s) = -2\sin(r)\sin(s).$

In the given problem, 
set $~\displaystyle \frac{a \pi}{2} = r, \frac{x \pi}{2} = s.$

So, in the original problem, in the 2nd factor, the right hand term becomes

$$\cos\left[\frac{\pi}{2}(a+x)\right] - 
\cos\left[\frac{\pi}{2}(a-x)\right]. \tag1 $$

Keeping in mind that (1) above involves continuous functions, as $x \to a$, the expression goes toward

$$\cos[\pi(a)] - \cos(0) = -2, \tag2 $$

since $a$ is an odd integer.

Actually, formally demonstrating the equivalence of (1) and (2) above may take some doing, since it is set against the backdrop of taking the limit of a quotient.  However, I make it at least $50\%$ that this is the problem composer's intent.

Given how things subsequently cancel out, I can't rule out there may be an alternative elegant approach that is easier to formally implement.

---

The equivalence between (1) and (2) above unlocks the problem.

Then, it is simply a matter of re-expressing:

$$\frac{a^2 + x^2}{ax} - 2.$$

Then, making $(ax)$ a common denominator, you should be able to cancel out the numerator.

Comment: Converting the sines to cosines is a good transformation, but it keeps the indeterminate form of infinity  - infinity. The value of 2 that you have calculated for cosines is the same as that of sines. It's important to note that the value of 2 can't be substituted independently of the other terms. In light of that can you give this another try?

Comment: I was able to solve it. I substituted x as a + h, converting the limit to h tends to zero. After simplification, the algebraic term splits into 2 + another term. This 2 along with cos can be written as sin using the half angle formula. Now we have two terms, both of which have an h^2 in the numerator which cancels with the h^2 in the denominator outside. Indeterminacy is resolved, and substituting h = 0 gives the answer.

Comment: @thewinster No, I am not allowed to, because your original posting has a number of defects.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.  My response was not an answer, or an attempt at an answer.  Instead, my response was a comment that was too long-winded for a comment box.  ...see next comment

Comment: @thewinster If you are able to solve it, why not improve the quality of your posting by editing your question?

Comment: I will add an answer in some time.